# Button Style Creators Update UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to get the effect of the button as in the windows 10 Creators Update apps.

Example Button Image

[image: Example Button].

I have already inserted the acrylic effect using the SDK:

MainPage.xaml Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="BaseGrid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicElementBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs Code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush myBrush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush();
        myBrush.BackgroundSource = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop;
        myBrush.TintColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37);
        myBrush.FallbackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37);
        myBrush.TintOpacity = 0.6;
        BaseGrid.Background = myBrush;
    }
}
```

But how is it possible to have the "light" effect of the mouse at its passage, the wave effect at the click?

Should it be a unique style?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am *extremely* familiar with the example you posted from the Maps app. The effect you are looking for is called [reveal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/reveal). There are a number of styles you can use to enable the effect on various controls (e.g., `ButtonRevealStyle` for buttons). For `AutoSuggestBox`, you are looking to enable the effect on the items inside the suggestions list.

> If you have a ListView and also have buttons or invokable content nested inside its ListViewItem elements, you should enable Reveal for the nested items.

To do this, you need to set the `ItemContainerStyle` property on `AutoSuggestBox` to a custom `ListViewItem` style that is based on the `ListViewItemRevealStyle`. If you are interested in what is going on in that style, you can check it out in generic.xaml.